# Object Construction in C++

Tags: c++, object, constructor, c++11

I am working on a small project in C++ that requires me to create an object of a custom class I wrote in another one of my classes. The class is called `FIRFilterModule`, It has a simple blank constructor.

Being of a java background, my impulse is to create it like this:

```
class SensorInput{
public:

  FIRFilterModule firFilter;
  ...More Class Members...
  SensorInput():firFilter(FIRFilterModule()){}
...};
```

However this compiles with the ever so helpful error message of "Error within this context". I'm a little lost why that doesn't work. Increasing my confusion I changed the code to this:

```
class SensorInput{
public:

  FIRFilterModule firFilter;
  ...More Class Members...
  SensorInput(){}
...};
```

It works.

Can someone help me understand why this is so?

Comment: Well as stated above, FIRFilterModule is a class i wrote, with a public constructor. firFilter is an object im creating in SensorInput. That was the complete error I got. the compiler im using is Wind River's default compiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, running of the default constructor for a member field, you don't have to do anything.  The constructor is run automatically.  So you can just write

```
class SensorInput{
public:

  FIRFilterModule firFilter;

  SensorInput() { ... }
};
```

The member initialization list is only needed when you need to call a constructor which has arguments or initialize POD types.  For example say the `FIRFilterModule` had a constructor which took an `int`.  Then you would use the memeber initialization list

```
SensorInput() : firFilter(42) { ... }
```

Comment: "You don't have to do anything" <= True.

You could also do SensorInput() : firFilter() { ... } if you prefer to be explicit though.

Comment: Does this apply when constructing FIRFilterModule anywhere? say for example i created one in my int main().

Comment: @jozefg yes. It applies to any place where an instance of `FIRFilterModule` is declared.  Note this is different than say `FIRFilterModule*`

Comment: "*The member initialization list is only needed when you need to call a constructor which has arguments.*" Or to initialize POD types, which would otherwise remain uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

[The code you posted is correct.](http://codepad.org/kMxv7y1j)

Maybe you forgot to include the header where `FIRFilterModule` is declared.

Otherwise, everything should work.

Comment: Sorry but nope... I included everything and triple checked FIRFilterModule. I asked others to look over my code as well, the bug is definitely in that code snippet.

Comment: @jozefg if it's in that snippet, copy the code I posted in your compiler and try it. If it doesn't work, your compiler is buggy.

Comment: @jozefg or maybe it's just telling you that the initialization is pointless as JaredPar mentioned.

Comment: @AlanStokes yes, I later commented on that and credited JaredPar.

Comment: Yeah my compiler is well frankly weird. It seems likely this was the source of the error.